# Get arguments from withing a script html tag given by the api

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

This topic has been discussed a lot but here is my problem.

I receive from my api an object containing a script

```
[
    {
        "script": "<script src=xxx.js></script>",
        "onScriptHead": true,
        "onScriptOnLoad": false,
    },
    {
        "script": "<script type=\"application/javascript\">do something else</script>",
        "onScriptHead": true,
        "onScriptOnLoad": false,
    }
]
```

Now my aim is to inject those script based on onScriptHead / onScriptLoad value.
I managed to create a code that can push a script on the head but only if there are no args inside the script tag

here is the code mentionned above

```
export const createScript = (scriptToInject: string, scriptSettings?: scriptSettingsProps) => {
  const { onScriptHead } = scriptSettings ?? {};

  const regexHTMLTag = /<([a-z]+)>/gi;
  const inverseScriptRegex = /<[^>]*script/gi;

  const addScriptTagToDom = (
    retrieveScriptData: RegExpExecArray | string | null,
    scriptTag?: any
  ) => {
    const newScript = scriptTag
      ? document.createElement(`${scriptTag}`)
      : document.createElement('script');
    if (Array.isArray(retrieveScriptData)) {
      const [, scriptData] = retrieveScriptData;
      newScript.innerHTML = scriptData;
    } else if (typeof retrieveScriptData === 'string') {
      newScript.innerHTML = retrieveScriptData;
    }
    document.head.append(newScript);
  };

  let match = regexHTMLTag.exec(scriptToInject);
  while (match !== null) {
    const scriptTag = match[1];
    const scriptRegex = new RegExp(`<${scriptTag}[^>]*>([\\s\\S]*?)</${scriptTag}>`);
    const finalScript = scriptRegex.exec(scriptToInject) ? scriptRegex.exec(scriptToInject) : '';

    if (onScriptHead) {
      addScriptTagToDom(finalScript, scriptTag);
    }
    match = regexHTMLTag.exec(scriptToInject);
  }

};
```

I cannot find a way to get the script, strip it down, then remount it using js document.xxx to use it in my dom

I have tried multiple regex and online solutions, but cannot find a dynamic way to inject my script after getting it from my api